# How to store a component in an object in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I import multiple icons in react app and store them in an array of objects, it looks like below:

```
export const icons = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        link: 'home',
        icon: <AiOutlineHome className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Favorite',
        link: 'favorite',
        icon: <BsHeart className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Search',
        link: 'search',
        icon: <IoSearchOutline className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Playing',
        link: 'playing',
        icon: <MdOutlineMovieCreation className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Upcoming',
        link: 'upcoming',
        icon: <BsCalendarDate className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Popular',
        link: 'popular',
        icon: <HiOutlineFire className="icon"/>,
    },
    {
        title: 'Popular',
        link: 'popular',
        icon: <AiOutlineStar className="icon"/>,
    },
]
```

Then I import them in another component and map through them to display all icons. So when file is `icons.js` it works alright, but when I change it to `icons.ts` I get an error: `'AiOutlineHome' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof AiOutlineHome'?` with all icons. Is there some way to solve it or should I just stick to using javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You need to name the extension to **.tsx** if you have JSX syntax in it.

Comment: it seems to solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to make it work? Not changing to .tsx extension?